# import resource is not working

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have just started learning Spring, it's easy two make several classes and pass the values in Spring configuration file via either construtor arg or setters.

What if I will give the an property reference to another configuration file, consider my simple program of two classes User and Vehical and two Spring COnfiguration files FirstBean.xml and SecondBean.xml and a App class with main method as follows -

**Directory Structure-**

[image]

**User.java -**

```
package com.common;

    public class User {

public String username;
public Vehical vehical;

public User() {
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Vehical getVehical() {
    return vehical;
}

public void setVehical(Vehical vehical) {
    this.vehical = vehical;
}
}
```

**Vehical.java -**

```
package com.common;

public class Vehical {

public String vehicalname;

public Vehical() {
}

public Vehical(String vehicalname) {
    super();
    this.vehicalname = vehicalname;
}

}
```

**App.java -**

```
package com.main;
import com.common.User;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/bean/FirstBean.xml");
    User user =(User) context.getBean("userClass");
    String s= user.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}

}
```

**FirstBean.xml -**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="com/bean/SecondBean.xml"/>

    <bean id="userClass" name="User" class="com.common.User">
        <property name="username" value="Sushant"></property>
        <property name="vehical" ref="vehicalClass"></property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

**SecondBean.xml -**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<bean id="vehicalClass" name="Vehical" class="com.common.Vehical">
    <constructor-arg value="pulser"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

In the FirstBean.xml I have imported resource of SecondBean.xml and gave reference to that by using ref but it's just not getting it. How can I solve this? I am not sure the thing I am trying to do is possible or not.

Comment: post the exception stack trace please

Comment: see first bean  property name vehical , i gave ref to vehicalClass that is not being recognized , vehicalClass bean is present in the another conf file SecondBean.xml . there are no errors its just eclipse could not resolve vehicalClass even after importing that resource of Secondbean.xml

Comment: Thanks it was pretty simple. But in spring docs its clearly mentioned to write the path , might be its becouse both of the xml's are in same directory. thanks once again.

Comment: I have updated my comment which worked into an answer, please accept it so that it becomes easier for future users. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<import resource="com/bean/SecondBean.xml"/>`

with `<import resource="SecondBean.xml"/>`